# How to Get APNS payload from a remote push notification?

Tags: ios, macos, apple-push-notifications

I am working on adding Remote push notification support in my OSX  application. I can successfully receive the push notification in my PC via apns and when I click the notification banner this is the behavior I am seeing.

If my app is not running , it will launch the application. But never hits on "ReceivedRemoteNotification()". Is this expected behavior ? Is there any way to receive the apns payload in this case ?

If my app is running I get the payload via "ReceivedRemoteNotification" and things are working fine.

So we cannot get apns payload in our app if it is not running?

Any help really appreciated.

thanks,
Jithesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The payload is available through "NSNotification" parameter of DidFinishLaunching.

```
 public override void DidFinishLaunching(NSNotification notification)
        {
            var uInfo = notification.UserInfo;
            if(uInfo["NSApplicationLaunchUserNotificationKey"] != null)
            {
                var payLoad = uInfo["NSApplicationLaunchUserNotificationKey"] as NSUserNotification;
                if(payLoad.ActivationType == NSUserNotificationActivationType.ActionButtonClicked)
                {
                    NSAlert alert = new NSAlert();
                    alert.MessageText = "Button Clicked";
                    alert.RunModal();
                }
                var userInfo = payLoad.UserInfo;

                //not.ActivationType == 
                if (userInfo != null && userInfo.ContainsKey(new NSString("aps")))
                {
                    //Get the aps dictionary
                    NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
                    if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("content")))
                    {
                        var deepLink = (aps[new NSString("content")] as NSString).ToString();
                        NSAlert alert = new NSAlert();
                        alert.MessageText = deepLink;
                        alert.RunModal();
                        //DisplaySubView(deepLink);
                        //Console.WriteLine($"Deeplink : {deepLink}");
                    }
                }

            }
```